# Cannot figure out what eats disk space, CentOS6

Tags: linux, centos, disk-space

Here is disk free info:

```
root@nqpc002/]# df -ha 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       103G   85G   13G  87% /
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       485M  112M  348M  25% /boot
/dev/sda5       2.0G  3.1M  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sdb1       879G  234G  601G  28% /mnt/ssd1t
none               0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
```

Trying to discover what eats the space on /dev/sda2/ which is reported to remain with 13G I run:

```
[root@NQPC002 /]# du -hs /* | sort -h
du: cannot access `/proc/2326/task/2326/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/2326/task/2326/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/2326/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/2326/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       /proc
0       /sys
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /selinux
4.0K    /srv
4.0K    /test.txt
16K     /lost+found
32K     /tmp
64K     /home
184K    /dev
1.5M    /opt
7.6M    /bin
14M     /sbin
23M     /lib64
30M     /etc
110M    /boot
389M    /lib
1.2G    /usr
1.6G    /root
15G     /var
234G    /mnt
```

and I really don't understand what ate 85G. Can you explain?

**UPDATE**

Solved the problem. I have recently deleted mongod.log without restartng mongod service. It continued to consume disk space. The solution is given in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34140/tell-fs-to-free-space-from-deleted-files-now

Comment: Can you run that as `du -hsx /* | sort -h` ?  I can see that `/mnt/ssd1t/` is an external drive, but what is in `/mnt/` (which is part of `/dev/sda2`)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) very useful for answering questions like this.
[image: ncdu is a text-mode disk exploration tool that sorts by size or date.]

Comment: Sorrowfully this proggy is useless in the above described situation.